# Почему JavaME приложение не запускается на реальном устройстве?

Tags: java, mobile

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

NetBeans.

На эмуляторе работает. На реальном устройстве - нет.
Ошибка при выполнении операции.

```
package mobileapplication2;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextBox;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author ItsGonnaBeMe
 */
public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    private Command exitCommand;
    private Display myDisplay;


    public void startApp() {
        myDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
    exitCommand = new Command("Выход",Command.EXIT,0); 
        TextBox t = new TextBox("Hello","Text",256,0);
        t.addCommand(exitCommand);
        t.setCommandListener(this);
        myDisplay.setCurrent(t);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает на настоящем телефоне?

Comment: Ошибка при выполнении операции.Тестировал на 2-х устройствах

Comment: Какой операции? По-моему, понятно, что этих слов недостаточно для определения проблемы. Код, кстати, нужно вставлять текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Да вот в том и дело. В консоли никаких ошибок. Скидываю jad и jar файлы на телефон. Установка проходит успешно. Запускаю -> Ошибка при выполнении операции.

Comment: На другом телефоне-> Ошибка Java.

Comment: 1. Добавьте-таки код в виде текста. Хочется знать, что это действительно весь ваш код: что нет других _.java_-файлов, и что в конце _Midlet.java_ больше ничего нет. 2. Добавьте в вопрос содержимое _.jad_-файла - возможно, проблема в нём. 3. Убедитесь, что телефоны сами по себе рабочие: что другие приложения на них нормально устанавливаются, и что не получилось каким-то образом, что на телефоне оказалось несколько версий вашего тестового приложения.

Comment: В проекте всего один класс Midlet. Тестировал на 2х устройствах . рабочие.

Comment: Ну вот, собственно, и ответ на вопрос: проблема в `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`. Удалите эту строку.

Comment: Попробую. Просто она автоматически прописываеться.

Comment: Прописывается-прописывается. А потом на некоторых телефонах приложение не запускается. "Веселье" то ещё.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло теперь ->Установка невозможна. Критические данные неправильно отформотриваны или не допустимы.

Comment: Какой вообще лучше выбрать MIDP-2.0 и CLDC 1.1?

Comment: В эмуляторе-то работает? А то, может, вы что-то лишнее в коде удалили. Какие настройки эмулятора выбирать - как правило, не важно. Но можете попробовать CLDC-1.0 и MIDP-1.0 - вдруг тогда и в эмуляторе ошибка появится. Лично я на поддержку телефонов на MIDP 1.0 почти сразу плюнул: на мой взгляд, после года так 2010 они стали совсем не актуальны.

Comment: Похоже заработало. Сейчас протестирую на другом проекте с канвас

Comment: То есть вы советуете все throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); Выкидывать?

Comment: Да. А ещё лучше в настройках NetBeans отредактировать соответствующий шаблон, чтобы эта строка вообще не добавлялась. Этот шаблон задан для Java методов в целом. В JavaME же это создаёт проблемы на ровном месте. Так всё же сейчас заработало, и проблема была именно в этом?

Comment: Да все заработало. Напиши ответ и я вам плюс поставлю. Спасибо большое. Единственная просьба ответь пожалуйста : Как я понимаю image надо в папку ресурсы ложить? Хочу сразу с андройд игру попробывать перенести. У меня книга Горнакова. Там другая среда разработки.

Comment: Ответ сейчас оформлю. При использовании настроек по умолчанию картинки нужно класть в папку `res`.

Comment: Хоспаде. Под эти балалайки все еще пишут? OMG

Comment: @Flippy пишут-пишут. Я до сих пор не выложил свою игру в Google Play, так что сейчас 40% входов в игру (при весьма скромном онлайне, но всё же) приходится на JavaME клиентов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вменяемого объяснения этому у меня нет, однако факт остаётся фактом:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

приводит к проблемам при запуске на некоторых моделях телефонов.

Проблема ли в самом `UnsupportedOperationException`, или в `throw`, или в отсутствии `throws` - непонятно.

Answer (score 3):

Вот тут этот баг объясняется для Nokia:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/_Zhlovy2qSM

> some old phones had broken firmware with missed classes

В вопросе не указано какой телефон используется.

**Дополнение, более правдоподобное.**
Это старый баг NetBeans, который отказались фиксить.
Среда генерирует некорректный шаблон, который работает в эмуляторе, но не является MIDP совместимым:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=127179